# How do I prevent a short flickering at dragstart in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drag-and-drop

I am trying to make a DIV draggable.
It all works quite well except for a shot flickering at startdrag.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MK01111000/48scq90y/3/) of the issue

Below is the code so far:

```
<template>
  <div>    
    <div id="mydiv" :style="{ top: cordY + 'px', left: cordX + 'px' }">
      <div id="mydivheader" draggable @dragstart="dragStart" @drag="dragging" @dragend="dragEnd">DRAG</div>
          <p>BLA</p>
          <p>BLA</p>
          <p>BLA</p>
    </div>    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data () {
    return {
      cordY: 200,
      cordX: 200,
      divY: 0,
      divX: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    dragStart: function (e) {
      var img = new Image()
      img.src = '../assets/nonexisting.png'
      e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10)
      this.divX = e.pageX - e.target.getClientRects()[0].left
      this.divY = e.pageY - e.target.getClientRects()[0].top
      this.cordY = e.pageY - this.divY
      this.cordX = e.pageX - this.divX
    },
    dragging: function (e) {
      this.cordY = e.pageY - this.divY
      this.cordX = e.pageX - this.divX
    },
    dragEnd: function (e) {
      this.cordY = e.pageY - this.divY
      this.cordX = e.pageX - this.divX
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The desired outcome is a draggable element without the flickering at the start.

Answer (score 2):

You solution has different issues in Firefox and Chrome.

**In Firefox**: you will meet the **flicker** issue when **dragstart** due to `e.pageX|Y` and `e.clientX|Y` is always **zero**. Look into [firefox Bugzilla #505521](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505521) for more details.

The workaround is listen the **dragover** event on document instead of **drag** in dragable element.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    cordY: 200,
    cordX: 200,
    divY: 0,
    divX: 0,
    delay: 20
  },
  mounted () {
    document.addEventListener('dragover', this.dragover, false) // remember to remove the event listener before some-when like Vue.beforeDestroy.
  },
  methods: {
    dragStart: function (e) {
      // https://learnvue.co/2020/01/how-to-add-drag-and-drop-to-your-vuejs-project/
      // HIDE GHOST/DRAG IMAGE BY REPLACING IT WITH A CUSTOM OR NONEXISTING IMAGE
      var img = new Image()
      img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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'
      e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10)
      this.divX = e.pageX - e.target.getClientRects()[0].left
      this.divY = e.pageY - e.target.getClientRects()[0].top
      this.cordY = e.pageY - this.divY
      this.cordX = e.pageX - this.divX
    },
    dragover: function (e) {
      this.cordY = e.pageY - this.divY
      this.cordX = e.pageX - this.divX

    },
    dragEnd: function (e) {

    }
  }
})
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  width:150px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  text-align: center;
  resize: both;
  overflow:auto
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div id="mydiv" :style="{ top: cordY + 'px', left: cordX + 'px' }">
      <div id="mydivheader" draggable @dragstart="dragStart" @dragend="dragEnd">DRAG</div>
        <p>BLA</p>
        <p>BLA</p>
        <p>BLA</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**In Chrome**: Uses one **setTimeout** to control the **Frame Rate** will improve the rendering.

You will find if data property=`this.delay` is 10 or less, the draggable element will flicker more often. If 20 or more, the flicker happens rarely.

And the flicker is caused by DraggingEvent.pageX/Y return (0, 0) sometimes for last frame before drag ends. I found someone asked similar questions in the Internet, but there is no good answer.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    cordY: 200,
    cordX: 200,
    divY: 0,
    divX: 0,
    timer: null,
    delay: 20,
    draging: false
  },
  methods: {
    dragStart: function (e) {
      // https://learnvue.co/2020/01/how-to-add-drag-and-drop-to-your-vuejs-project/
      // HIDE GHOST/DRAG IMAGE BY REPLACING IT WITH A CUSTOM OR NONEXISTING IMAGE
      var img = new Image()
      img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAwJCRcVExgWFhYaGBcaGB0dHh0XHxoeGhYXIR0lJSAdIB8mLTwxJik4Kh8gMkkzOD5AREVFJTBMUktNUj1DRUUBDQ4OExETJhUVJUUnJSdBQUFBQUFFQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFFQUFBQUFBRUFBRUFBQUFFQUFFQUVBQUFFQUFBQf/AABEIAGQAZAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAACAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBQADBgIBB//EADQQAAEDAgMFBgQGAwAAAAAAAAEAAgMEERIhMQUGQVFhEyJxgZGxFDJioSNCU8HR8AdSov/EABgBAAMBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQA/8QAIREAAgICAgIDAQAAAAAAAAAAAAECEQMhEjEEQRQiURP/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AE+zaMPJLhk3hzKcBiD2U4WLeOqZtCwy7NiJHQ9q0tw3dwsM0CNiz/pOyy0W/wB36djIQ63edr6pqIgTcqscVq2SlkpmA2dudLIQZO437p/DuRTjUFx8VpwF6qrGkTc2zOt3Opgb4L+ypl3KgLbN7py9s1qF4m4IHJmLbuOwOu5xIvkBy5I9u6NKRazh5rSqmVvJDhEPOR863j2C2mcCwkseTkfy9L+qV00oyYfLwWp3qeXNaDwcVmOyGvFZsiSkaIO1sK7I8lEJnzUSDgsbSDcZFMI6x3EArjsV2yJMIbHd6cvibwsSFpWrObtwhsd1ogVrj0jNLs7UXOJQOTCnSi5uh6uvihbilkbG3S7iBc8hzXHBN1y5DUdfFOzHDI2Rh/Mwhwv4hXErjjP7zUBkju3Ue3FZ6GiZhsbkra1zcTCOYWUlhLSVmzLdl8T1QIaBvAlRXF5UULLAAYrWRq+OK6IbGOS6wGg2SQIwmockdDLYAJrHIt66Mj7EO+G0nwsh/CfLE5zg9sTixzyG3Y24zte5IGuHyOc/x9JVtqntlxtiexz+zeSez7wwkA5tvdwtxtfgvoM7GSNLHtDmnUOAIPkqqWliiBETGsBNzhAFzzKNy69BtUey7YhbMIHSWkIuBY2tnnfTgVkd9YKztw+B7WxyU5hJcLhl3Ev7wBLS4YM/p6BaOXYtO+TtHRNLs/DPXLrx5o/HZDfo5OmYz/Hew5aUzOc68b2t0xBrngnNt9bC2fG/RblzlT2q5c9dv2Bu2cVDsktkgDgQSiJ5kGH5EpMq+o0HsWSR2NvZRXEKLGaS2kom4BJK7Azhzd4K8Mp3D8OQ4uTrZpHtOrMkgZezWjIdAqw4CxGRHJJdqw8TQQxm1wb2NiOXVN4ZBZZ2gnxXPNMmX4FXxeQkqkSni3aD5ZghPjRey9EZOp9FZFSxjVoPinl5MF1sRYmVfGrk1qM7GP8ATCrfCz/QIPyl+BWJllPIOKufI2yWlltCqnyO5p/kY6B/KR7NGXH5gB1uq5w0NAb1zOpVEktkLPNdo81mlmc3Xossaijt0gUQDnqIBAZsxj6WK4jqLFUUdWCLH5XZHoVJaCUG7Gl7OBaL+qSOtMo97HWzpLaZC+nJO4ZVlKF7m3DgRoc03p6pTmthRoGSKwPSllSrRUpDqGWNcOkQPxKrdUI2CgmSZBSzKqSdCSTLhqJPOh+37qpmffIJbVVlnYRwyVIK2BjB1ULr1IjVqK3EQCp5Sw5aHUHQphFXAfLI6M8syPUJI9/X7heCVvEhU42LdDwVlnXx4vI/um8M2Joc3T2KxwnbwIRdHtYwuuLEcQdCOqSWO1oZTNfHVK8VSS020o5Rf5Tyv+6KDeRWZxoqmmMfiV4ahA4HKBpQoIS6ZUukJXJLR8xHqlVdt8MJZGLuHEjIeA4powctIVySDaupETfrIy6dUiz8fFCuqnPOJ1yTzREZHL3WiMOKJ8rPc/6FFeCOv3XqNhoUEXXIgBUUVESZW+ID+heRsBKiiNgDGNw5gkI6lqCTb2yUUU2MhpG48z6ldP0OZ8yVFFEoKJ6lxNtPDVASQNuooqrRNlLmBuiKhfa3dB6m/wDKiidgQW2o+lv/AF/KiiiAx//Z'
      e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10)
      this.divX = e.pageX - e.target.getClientRects()[0].left
      this.divY = e.pageY - e.target.getClientRects()[0].top
      this.cordY = e.pageY - this.divY
      this.cordX = e.pageX - this.divX
      this.draging = true
    },
    dragging: function (e) {
        if (this.timer) return;
      this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.timer = null
        if (!this.draging) return
        this.cordY = e.pageY - this.divY
        this.cordX = e.pageX - this.divX
      }, this.delay)
    },
    dragEnd: function (e) {
        this.draging = false
      this.cordY = e.pageY - this.divY
      this.cordX = e.pageX - this.divX
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  width:150px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  text-align: center;
  resize: both;
  overflow:auto
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div id="mydiv" :style="{ top: cordY + 'px', left: cordX + 'px' }">
      <div id="mydivheader" draggable @dragstart="dragStart" @drag="dragging" @dragend="dragEnd">DRAG</div>
        <p>BLA</p>
        <p>BLA</p>
        <p>BLA</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is one gif it shows how the DND works in the Chrome: [image]

> As I tried so far, uses **dragover** solution seems work fine in both
> Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I see no difference when I run your snippet. It still flickers.

Comment: try `this.delay=30`, it may be better. In my computer, I didn't see the flickers when `this.delay=20`.

Comment: In your computer, the flicker happened when place the element(end of the drag) into new position, right?

Comment: I tried 30, 50 and even 100 but the flickering persists.

Comment: To double conofirm, the flickers happened when place the element (ending the drag) into new position, right? And I tried above codes in another computer but didn't see the flickers. Could you make a gif to show us the flickers?

Comment: @MK01111000 I added one gif at the end of the answer, does it meet your requirements?

Comment: it's not about the "ghost image", nor a flickering at the end of the drag. There is a short flickering at the *start* of the drag. It's like the element is just for split moment taken approx 50px to the top and approx 50px to the left

Comment: OK, it seems you uses Firefox, Please check the updated answer works or not.

Comment: I am not using Firefox and the flickering is not solved with your last update. Thanks however for trying!

Answer (score 0):

(3 years later)
The flickering is because the drag image is not yet rendered when it is set to be the drag image. You can get rid of the flickering by creating a drag image in advance, instead of in the event handler, and storing it at an out-of-window coordinate.

Chrome is buggy in the way it handles drag images (September 2023). They must be in the DOM, and the drag image includes the composite of whatever is in front and behind it in the DOM, usually the body background, so transparency doesn't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).